# Check for duplicates and submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

EDIT: I am using Code Igniter: www.codeigniter.com

So I'm new to web developement and programming in general and I've been playing around with PHP and started developing a little website and i want to make it easier for users to submit.

I have 9 radio buttons (oh and I'm using code igniter)

```
    <?php
    echo form_radio('name1', '3')." 3 ";
    echo form_radio('name1', '2')." 2 ";
    echo form_radio('name1', '1')." 1 ";
    echo form_radio('name2', '3')." 3 ";
    echo form_radio('name2', '2')." 2 ";
    echo form_radio('name2', '1')." 1 ";
    echo form_radio('name3', '3')." 3 ";
    echo form_radio('name3', '2')." 2 ";
    echo form_radio('name3', '1')." 1 ";
    $submit = Array ("name" => 'submit', "value" => 'Submit', "class" => "g-button large");
    echo form_submit($submit);
    echo form_close();
    ?>
```

So i want something to check for duplicates and display an error (preferable a div) without reloading the page and i would also like the form to submit without the submit button (for example hotornot.com but with 3 sets of radio buttons).

I understand this needs jQuery and possibly AJAX (?) and i'm completely clueless with them both. And also i saw this: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ and i tried tinkering with it but i had nfi what i was doing.

Comment: there is no radiobuttions in your code, but some PHP code only. first thing you have to learn about web development is that you're developing HTML code.

Comment: I'm using code igniter: 
echo form_radio('name1', '3'); translates to:
<input type="radio" name="name1" value="3" />

Comment: That seems a little harsh; form_radio is part of the CI framework, by the look of it, and will produce an HTML radio button - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: yes, that's the point. these translated HTML buttons should be your question, not PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use every helper in CI; I wouldn't use form helper, at least for the radio buttons as you'll need to include onClick event handler into radio button html code:

```
<input type="radio" name="name1" value="3" onclick="set_info('send_something')" />
<div id="info">&nbsp;</info>
```

this part should be put between  tags in your html code, above radio buttons of course:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
set_info=function(send_something){
$('#info').html(send_something);
}
</script>
```

the last one includes jQuery code of course and you sould include it too:

```
<script type="text/javascipt" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

I hope that this code snippets give you more than basic idea where your coding should go for this case.